# C/C++ option not available in NetBeans11 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-center, c++, 19.04, netbeans

After installing NetBeans 11 on a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 systen using the `Ubuntu Software` center, Netbeans did not provide the option to create C++ projects.

Following the instructions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/972861) did not work. The Netbeans Distribution update center was already enabled by default, but the list of available plugins did not include any C++ plugins.

What is the proper way to get C++ support with NetBeans 11 using Ubuntu 19.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Update Center labeled "NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal" . It appears that C++ is not in the latest distribution yet, so I had add the legacy Update Center.
[image]

After adding this update center, I was able to locate and install the C++ plugin using the method shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/972861/680966), and then create a C++ HelloWorld program in NetBeans 11 on Ubuntu 19.04 
[image]